# Talend: Aggregation summary?

Tags: talend

I've seen how to use tMap in TOS to map different fields in a SQL-like JOIN. How do I aggregate based on certain fields?

If I have two tables:

```
[ A, B, C, D ]
and               that are tMap'ped to  [ B, C, F, G ]
[ B, E, F, G]
```

how can I aggregate the results to that instead of the many entries of the non-unique B I can see something like:

```
[ B, count(B), avg(C), avg(F), avg(G) ]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Update: I don't even know if Talend can do this. Ended up using Awk instead. But the question is still open!

Answer (score 5):

**You certainly can.** Use the tAggregate component to do that. You can group by column B and then compute all of the different aggregations, like count, sum, and average in the other columns.